# Add closing tags to user supplied marked down text if necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, bbcode

I'm VERY new to jQuery.

I'm taking user supplied input from the database and displaying it on screen. First thing I do is scrub it of characters that could cause harm:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
    return text
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

Next, allow them to use a few emoji's (thanks to the wonderful Twemoji CSS i found somewhere):

```
function emote(text) {
    return text
        .replace(':)',   '<i class="twa twa-smiley"></i>')
        .replace(';)',   '<i class="twa twa-wink"></i>')
        .replace(':(',   '<i class="twa twa-frowning"></i>');
```

Everything is good so far.

This last one is proving to be a sort of a headache - allowing a little bit of markup:

```
function formatHtml(text) {
    return text
        .replace("[b]",  "<strong>")
        .replace("[/b]", "</strong>")
        .replace("[i]",  "<em>")
        .replace("[/i]", "</em>");
}
```

If someone forgets a closing tag, it obviously spills over to other areas of the document. Not sure what the best solution for this is. Should a flag every time a tag is opened, and if it's not closed at the end of their input, insert one via script? So it won't be a simple replace any more, but a find opening tag, replace that, then look for closing tag and replace that if it exists, otherwise insert one at the end of their input.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Also advice about escapeHTMML() - I lifted if from an older SO post, looks great to me, but not sure if there is any worry about it being circumvented (as, again, I'm very new to jQuery)...

Comment: This is more bbcode than markdown, maybe ou need a [bbcode parser](https://github.com/Frug/js-bbcode-parser)?

Comment: suggest you look for matches before replacing and make sure they exist before user is allowed to save to server

Comment: @HuguesMoreau - the BBCode parsers I found look like they expect both tags to be there as well.

Comment: @Charlietfl - Yeah - I guess add that to the validation rules on the backend.

Comment: That's very possible, but that's still bbcode and not markdown ;) Maybe you can edit your tags to describe the question better?